# Property 'dispatch' is missing in type error when passing root store to root component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-router, react-router-v4

I am getting started with typescript and redux and I came across the following error when bootstrapping my application.

```
Type '{ store: Store<IRootState>; }' is not assignable to type 
'IntrinsicAttributes & Store<IRootState> & { children?: ReactNode; }'. 
 Type '{ store: Store<IRootState>; }' is not assignable to type 'Store<IRootState>'.
 Property 'dispatch' is missing in type '{ store: Store<IRootState>; }'.
```

I have the following root component being rendered:

```
const Root: React.SFC<Store<IRootState>> = (store) => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router>
      <Route exact={true} path="/" component={App} />
    </Router>
  </Provider>
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Root store={RootStore}/>,
//......~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);
```

The error is occurring in the line`store={RootStore}`. Here `RootStore` is the result of calling `createStore` on my root reducer and initial state. Initial state's type is `IRootState` which is pretty basic:

```
export interface IRootState {
    navBar: INavBarState;
}
```

and the Root store is exported as follows:

```
const RootStore = createStore(rootReducer, initialState);
export default RootStore;
```

If I understand this correctly (which I'm sure I don't), the error is happening because the parameter `dispatch` isn't present on the return value of `createStore`. But since this is a library function, I'm inclined to believe that I'm missing something pretty obvious over here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that for `Root`, you declare the props as an object of type `Store<IRootState>`, rather than an object with a `store` property of type `Store<IRootState>`. Hence the error `'{ store: Store<IRootState>; }' is not assignable to type 'Store<IRootState>'`

Wrapping the type parameter and the `store` parameter should do the trick:

```
const Root: React.SFC<{store: Store<IRootState>}> = ({store}) => (
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I knew it was something pretty basic which I was missing.